# Naming things articles

Tags: articles

When I name things which I like for example: I like burger, apple, banana. Is it ok to use no articles? Or I need to say I like a burger, an apple. A banana

Comment: Use articles or plurals without article: burgers, apples, bananas.  Apple and banana without articles can refer to the *flavors* not the fruit.

Answer (score 1):

Name some foods you like.

> I like burgers, apples, bananas, cupcakes. And I don't say no thank you to cherry pie. A pear with some cheese is a tasty snack, or a juicy freestone peach.

Comment: Or when I say to prepare fruit salad you need sugar an apple, a banana. I put articles or plurals right?

Comment: If all you need is one, yes.

Comment: Does is sound natural when I say: I must have two apples to prepare this this or maybe I need two apples sounds more natural?

Comment: **need** is more natural. Or you could say "The recipe *calls for* two apples".

Comment: Which version is proper my favourite dish is a fruit salad or just fruit salad and why?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten this advice on other questions, but just so it's provided here:

- When talking in the abstract about things that you could count, the easiest thing is to use plurals, with no article: **"I like burgers.**
- If it's something you wouldn't count, use a singular with no article: **"I like salt."**

There could be more complicated usages for more complicated situations, but I think this question is looking for a simple answer.