# Are articles used with names of meals, as in "My favourite dish is (a) fruit salad"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, zero-article

When do we use articles before dishes? For example, "My favourite dish is a fruit salad" or no article. Are there any rules?

Comment: Didn't you just ask a similar question?

Comment: Someone told me to make a new thread

Comment: Yes, it was not clear and not properly written. This is better, yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Naming things articles](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346087/naming-things-articles)

Comment: A "dish" is something less generic  than "fruit salad", for example *coq au vin* or "cherries jubilee" or "shepherd's pie" or "baked Alaska".

Comment: Desserts are not dishes.

Answer (score 5):

There is no set rule on whether a certain word or phrase takes an article or not. It depends on what you are trying to say, and whether the article is appropriate for the context.

For example:

"My favorite dish is fruit salad" - This does not use an article; you are talking about the general idea of fruit salad, and not about a specific fruit salad.

"My favorite dish last night was a fruit salad" - Your favorite dish last night was a specific fruit salad, but one that the listener does not know about.

"My favorite dish last night was the fruit salad" - Your favorite dish last night was a specific fruit salad that the lister knows about.

"I ate fruit salad last night" - Fruit salad was a thing that you ate last night.

"I ate a fruit salad last night" - You ate a specific fruit salad last night which the listener does not know about.

"I ate the fruit salad last night" - You ate a specific fruit salad that is known to the listener.

Comment: But for example with the word omelet I awalys use articles right?

Comment: @Samgra Not necessarily, you can say "My favourite dish is cheese omelette."

Comment: Can we say then that almost all names of meals or disheas like pizza spagheti omelette and so on take no article as long as we don't want to be specific?

Comment: @Samgra I answered your quesiton. Pizza is not really a "dish". I had pizza for dinner.

Comment: Can I say? I like sandwich with no article?

Comment: @Samgra You would normally say "I like sandwiches" for that sentence.

Comment: Fruit salad is generally uncountable as a food that you eat. You don't have "one fruit salad" or "two fruit salads". Because of that, it's "I like fruit salad," but "I like sandwiches." That said, batches or portions of fruit salad can be treated as countable, so "there were two fruit salads at the party tonight."

Comment: The word omelet behaves like the word sandwich. I mean it's generally countable right?

Comment: Yes. If you say "I ate two omelettes this morning," you mean that you ate two discreet objects, each one of which is an omelette. If you say "I ate two fruit salads this morning," it means you ate portions that came from two separate preparations of fruit salad. So "I like omelettes."

Comment: A lot of foods have a core uncountable usage and then one or more countable usages. For the sentence "I like x," you use the singular for generally uncountable foods and plural for the ones that are always countable.

Comment: What about when I want to say I like Mac royal do  I need any article here?

Comment: Omelet is generally countable, because it refers to separate items that are ordered and served singularly, but if you were talking about an eggy mass in general you might use the non-countable version: "I don't like omelet, it's too stodgy". With something like a burger, you'd normally use the plural ("I like Mac royals") although could use other forms, e.g. if you were talking about which McDonalds items you like you might say "I like the Mac royal" because you both know the item under discussion.

Comment: **My favorite food is** is not the same as **My favrorite food *last night***, which changes the whole thing.

Comment: @Lambie I interpret "My favorite food is {x}" as being an example sentence in the question, whereas the actual question is about whether meals as a class never take an article.

Comment: No, the actual question is not about whether meals as a class never take an article. It is about whether terms like fruit salad  do or do. And I wish someone else would inform the OP that fruit salad is not a dish.

Comment: @Lambie Where I'm from, fruit salad is a side dish and not a dessert. Not sure whether everyone would consider that enough to call it a dish, but it seems reasonable to call it one to me (though I take TimR's point that it's too generic to qualify).

Comment: @YonKuma It is not that it is generic. In any case, a side dish is not a dish. A dish in Eng;ish refers to cooked food or main dish.

Answer (score 1):

You use the article "a" with singular countable nouns, but not when used attributively.  In your examples, you would never use an article, but you may need to use a plural.

Some foods (and other words) are usually countable. In your example, you'd use a plural. There is no article with indefinite plural:

> I like chips / I like apples / I like hats.

Some foods are non-count:

> I like rice /  I like cheese / I like spotted dick.

You don't see "a" or "an" with these.

Some foods have both a countable and non-countable form.  The countable is for counting the food when it comes in countable servings.

> I would like three coffees.  I want two fruit salads.

But if you are talking about these foods as a substance, you would use them as non-count nouns

> My favourite drink is coffee. My favourite food is fruit salad.

You'll need to learn when a food can be treated as uncountable.  Sometimes it is easy to guess, sometimes you may be surprised.

Comment: What about when I want to say I like Mac royal do I need any article here?

Comment: You never need an article, but you need to decide if you need plural or not.  Try to decide if the plural "Mac Royals" works.

Comment: With mac royal I need no article because it is more like a proper name is that right? For example when I say my favourite dish an omelet I use an article because the word omelet i always countable and mac royal would be only countable when i refer to portions yes?

Comment: No.  Please read my answer again.  In the expressions  "I like {}" you never use an article.  You either use an uncountable noun  "I like coffee", or you use a plural  "I like apples".  "Mac Royal" (which I assume is some type of hamburger, it's not sold in the UK) is countable.  "I like Mac Royals".    "I like omelettes".   "I like cheese".  No articles in these sentences only plurals and non-count singular.

Comment: But "I want {}" is different.  "I want a Mac Royal",  "I want an omelette".  "I want some cheese".

Comment: Ok. I get it but what when I want to say for example: my favourite dish is omelet or an omelet or mac royal or a mac royal. Next example To prepare mac royal or a mac royal you need this and that?

Comment: To prepare a Mac Royal you need ....

Comment: Whag about my favourite dish? Btw thank you for helping as much

Comment: Either use plural or non-count.  But you probably won't ever use "dish" since you are not talking about "dishes" but about "food".  Here's an extended example "My favourite food is omelette {non count}" But the omelette {determined, specific} last night was dry and tasteless.  I ate a Mac Royal {singular} in the airport on the way home, and my favourite dish last week was the Mac Royal {determined}."  If any of the use of articles here is surprising to you, please start a new question!

Comment: Ok thanks only one more question and that's it. I can say my favourite dish is pizza, omelet or Mac royal no article right? But when i say to prepare a pizza or an omlelet i have to use articles?

Comment: Yes, but "food" seems more approriate than dish.

Answer (score -2):

My favorite dessert is fruit salad.
My favorite dish is potatoes au gratin.
My favorite food is ice cream.
My favorite food is fried chicken.
My favorite main course is roast beef.

All those are general ideas and taking the food as an uncountable noun. No determiner.

**COMPARE**:
There was ***a fruit salad*** served inside a hollowed-out pineapple.
***An ice cream*** is what I like for dessert.
***A piece of fried chicken*** can be very tasty.
There was **a fruit salad** on the dining table.
The fruit salad was on the table.

A/the/plural as needed for a **countable** noun.
*There were three different **fruit salads** on the table.
*That kid ate three ice creams!

A fruit salad is not usually called a "dish".
A dish is usually main course food or cooked food.

None of those, in simple form as above, takes a determiner.

Comment: Disregard the downvoters. I gave examples only for this usage.

Comment: I would disagree about not calling a fruit salad a dish. On the other hand an apple or a Mars bar would not be called a dish.

Comment: @Peter I suggest you check some menus written by English speakers.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing the word "dish" actually used in a menu. But perhaps there are regional differences in the use of the word.

Comment: @Peter For example, for the term dish: https://thedefineddish.com/

Comment: Also see https://www.wordnik.com/words/dish. I have often had fruit salad prepared and served in a dish, so the 5th meaning applies.

Comment: @Peter It has nothing to do with it being served in a dish per se.  "My favorite dish is fruit salad". That is not the same meaning...

Comment: From Wordnik (The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 5th Edition), 5th meaning, *The food served or contained in a dish*. Your example "My favorite dish is fruit salad" is perfectly natural usage where I come from.

Comment: @Peter I already acknowledged food served in a dish. I don't agree that fruit salad is a dish. It is a side, it is a dessert, And generally, we don't go around saying "My favorite dish is X". We'd say: My favorite food is X,.

Comment: I think we need to put this down to regional differences. Our usage of "side" is also different. Just for clarification - by fruit salad I mean a variety of fruit cut up into bite-sized pieces and mixed together. It is may be presented in a large bowl or dish, but is eaten from individual bowls, normally with a spoon (and optional fork).

Comment: @Peter I don't think there is any misunderstanding about what a fruit salad is in English.